# asp.net core authorization - Operation authorization handler

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, resources, authorization

I have strange problem and can not debug it.

I am trying to use `OperationAuthorizationRequirement` and an `AuthorizationHandler`.

When I place breakpoint in controller, I always get 403 result, so I tried to place breakpoint inside `CountryControllerAuthorizationHandler`, and it is never triggered. But in controller, I always get result of `AuthorizeAsync  false` but i cannot understand why i cannot get breakpoint being hit or triggered. Am I doing some stupid mistake? Anyway as I can see, resource is `NOT null` and also User and claims are `NOT null`:

Here is my code:

CountryControllerAuthorizationHandler:

```
public class CountryControllerAuthorizationHandler : AuthorizationHandler<OperationAuthorizationRequirement, Country>
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context,
                                                   OperationAuthorizationRequirement requirement,
                                                   Country resource)
    {
        if (requirement.Name == Operations.ReadDetail.Name &&
            context.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Type == "userType")?.Value == "customer"
            )
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }

        if (requirement.Name == Operations.Create.Name &&
            context.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Type == "userType")?.Value == "1"
            )
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }

        if (requirement.Name == Operations.Update.Name &&
            context.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Type == "userType")?.Value == "1"
            )
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }

        if (requirement.Name == Operations.Delete.Name &&
           context.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Type == "userType")?.Value == "1"
           )
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Operations class:

```
public static class Operations
{
    public static OperationAuthorizationRequirement Create =
        new OperationAuthorizationRequirement { Name = nameof(Create) };
    public static OperationAuthorizationRequirement Read =
        new OperationAuthorizationRequirement { Name = nameof(Read) };
    public static OperationAuthorizationRequirement ReadDetail =
      new OperationAuthorizationRequirement { Name = nameof(ReadDetail) };
    public static OperationAuthorizationRequirement Update =
        new OperationAuthorizationRequirement { Name = nameof(Update) };
    public static OperationAuthorizationRequirement Delete =
        new OperationAuthorizationRequirement { Name = nameof(Delete) };
}
```

Startup.cs:

```
services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, CountryControllerAuthorizationHandler>();

services.AddMvcCore()
    .AddAuthorization()
    .AddJsonFormatters();

services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
    .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        options.ApiName = "api1";
    });
```

And finally controller:

```
public CountriesController(ICountryService service, IAuthorizationService authorizationService)
{
    _authorizationService = authorizationService;
    this.countryService = service;
}

public async Task<object> GetDetail()
{
    var obj = countryService.Get_DETAILS();
    var authorizationResult = await _authorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(User, obj, Operations.ReadDetail);

    if (authorizationResult.Succeeded)
    {
        return Ok(obj);
    }
    else if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        return new ForbidResult();
    }
    else
    {
        return new ChallengeResult();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just so I understand this correctly: You are able to hit a breakpoint in your controller action, and you do get an unsuccessful result from the `AuthorizeAsync` call. But there’s no breakpoint being hit inside of your authorization handler? What type does `countryService.Get_DETAILS()` return? Is this the same `Country` type that you are using for the authorization handler?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `countryService.Get_DETAILS()` is **not null** and only return **one Country**.

For `CountryControllerAuthorizationHandler`, it accepts `Country`, so, only one county object is passed will be passed into `HandleRequirementAsync`.

`HandleRequirementAsync` is called by `HandleAsync` in `AuthorizationHandler`.

Try to make a test with code below to debug the reason `HandleRequirementAsync` is not called.

```
    public class CountryControllerAuthorizationHandler : AuthorizationHandler<OperationAuthorizationRequirement, Country>
{
    public override async Task HandleAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context)
    {
        if (context.Resource is Country)
        {
            foreach (var req in context.Requirements.OfType<OperationAuthorizationRequirement>())
            {
                await HandleRequirementAsync(context, req, (Country)context.Resource);
            }
        }
    }
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context,
                                                   OperationAuthorizationRequirement requirement,
                                                   Country resource)
    {
        if (requirement.Name == Operations.ReadDetail.Name &&
            context.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Type == "userType")?.Value == "customer"
            )
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }

        if (requirement.Name == Operations.Create.Name &&
            context.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Type == "userType")?.Value == "1"
            )
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }

        if (requirement.Name == Operations.Update.Name &&
            context.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Type == "userType")?.Value == "1"
            )
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }

        if (requirement.Name == Operations.Delete.Name &&
           context.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Type == "userType")?.Value == "1"
           )
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```